# Code suddenly crashes

Tags: android, loops, pointers, crash, null

I have been working with the following code for quite a while now

```
int[] icons = { R.drawable.heart,       R.drawable.clock, 
                        R.drawable.calculator,  R.drawable.pizza,
                        R.drawable.calendar,    R.drawable.email};

        OnClickListener[] listeners = { _handleCheckin,     _handleTimer,
                                        _handleCalculator,  _handleCalories,
                                        _handleCalendar,    _handleEmail };

        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            String buttonID = "button" + i;
            int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(buttonID, "id", "com.msimionescu.mydiabetes");
            Button b = ((Button) findViewById(resID));

            b.setBackgroundResource(icons[i]);
            b.setWidth(50);
            b.setHeight(50);

            b.setOnClickListener( listeners[i] );

            b.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                     switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                            v.getBackground().setColorFilter(0x66000000,PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                            v.invalidate();
                            break;
                        }
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                            v.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
                            v.invalidate();
                            break;
                        }
                     }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

All of a sudden, it started crashing, invoking a null pointer in the for loop. Technically, it can't find the buttons.

Is there a possibility my R file has been corrupted or something? I tried to manually configure each button and it still crashes. Yes, my buttons have the correct ids. I'm seriously stumped here, I hope someone can shed light on this.

Thanks.

Comment: try cleaning the project. Then try finding your button if they appear then the R File is proper

Comment: Does it happen for every value of `i`? Also, it would help if you posted the layout file in which the buttons are to be found.

Comment: What does the LogCat say?

Answer (score 0):

```
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(buttonID, "Button", "com.msimionescu.mydiabetes");
```